# Two Maven Errors - 'Type Cannot Be Resolved' + aspect weaver.1.8.0.M1 missing

Tags: java, spring, macos, maven, aspectj

I have two errors on an existing mvm project I am trying to build and not sure how to get these resolved.

First the **main one**:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.5:compile (default) on project ws: Compiler errors:
The type java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

This one is bugging me a bit, I mean this is from the main JRE so I am not sure what this error means. I am building this from the command line and not through Eclipse or other IDEs at this stage. Most answers on the web seem to be based on putting the JRE on the project build path within eclipse.

I have Java 1.8 installed, running on OSX. My Java Source+Target version is 1.7.

The second is a warning, which I am not too fussed but I would like to remove it if I can:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.0.M1 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Now I believe this is coming from Spring-Aspects-4.0 which I have dependency on, I have set an explicit decency on the POM to 1.7.4 (stable).

Anyway I can remove this warning, or do I need to put a dependency on the 1.8.0.M1 on my POM which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right so after much tinkering, it seems the issue was that the environment it was being built on, had a JDK 8 installed and the aspectjweaver version was not compatible with it.

Therefore two solutions:

1. Install JDK7 and set that as the JAVA_HOME before building.

or

1. Set source/target to 1.8, set aspectjweaver to 1.8.1 version and that works.

The error message wasn't clear but it's sorted now.

Comment: This helped, I need to generate 1.6 sources for a legacy app. So I also kept <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel> for the aspectj plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue while building my project with maven.

`[ERROR] The type java.lang.RuntimeException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

I have Java 1.8 and Java 17 installed, running on MacOS M1, with Source+Target version set to 1.8 and `aspect weaver` complianceLevel set to 1.8

I run this command to see the installed JDKs on my machine:
`/usr/libexec/java_home -V` which gave the following output:

`Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):`

```
17 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 17" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
15.0.2 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 15" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_312 (x86_64) "Amazon" - "Amazon Corretto 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_312/Contents/Home`
```

It amounted to my environment not set up properly. I had the JAVA_HOME pointing to JDK 17

`java -version`

`java version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)`

I was able to compile and build my project successfully after running this command :

`unset JAVA_HOME`

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v "1.8.0_312")`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).